# How to deploy maven generated war file to STS's tc server?

Tags: war, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've created a maven project from a spring-ws example and imported into STS (by using mvn eclipse:eclipse and importing it).  It comes with a war file, which I'd like to deploy to the server, from STS or otherwise. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be as follows:

1. remove your project from STS
2. run mvn eclipse:clean on the command line
3. import the mavan project into STS as a maven project and use m2eclipse
4. Open the servers view
5. Drag and drop the project onto the server

This should be sufficient for deploying onto tcServer.  You may be able to skip steps 1-3, but I am not sure if your maven generated .project file will be sufficient for WTP to know that the project can be run on tcServer.  Worth a try, but I think you'll have to do the full 5 steps.